# How to auto resize the text area element on load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created an auto expanding textarea element that dynamically grows based on the text content within it which works great. I do this by looking at the scroll height and then adding this to the height of the textarea.

The problem I have is when I load text into the same textarea on initial load via the value prop - it reverts back to it's initial height and only auto expands when I focus in on the textarea and hit enter which means it's cropping out a lot of the content (especially where multi-line items are concerned).

I've been trying to come up with a workaround for a while and I haven't managed to find a solution as of yet. Is there a way I can determine the scroll height of the container as if the user had typed something on mount to expand the textarea to the same height?

Edit: Apologies for the confusion, the issue comes when I recall the same text that was entered from a database into the same textfield

(added photos to demonstrate my issue)

Added photos:
[Text when added in textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUCbS.png)

[Same text on load/mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZzvk.png)

(on the second image, you can see that the text area has gone back to it's original height after the text has been saved to a database and injected back into the same textarea)

Comment: So you want to find a easier way for you to auto-expand textarea. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Adding an useEffect to track when the the content of the texarea is changing and updating the size should work I think.

Comment: @Shawn in a way, yes but more so on load so that it expands when there is text already in it, so perhaps via a useEffect or via refs?

Comment: @Berci what property would I track? Scroll height on mount is 0 and clientHeight just tracks the viewable viewport height

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("textarea").height( $("textarea")[0].scrollHeight );
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>


I have created an auto expanding textarea element that dynamically grows based on the text content within it which works great. I do this by looking at the scroll height and then adding this to the height of the textarea.

The problem I have is when I load text into the same textarea on initial load via the value prop - it reverts back to it's initial height and only auto expands when I focus in on the textarea and hit enter which means it's cropping out a lot of the content (especially where multi-line items are concerned).

I've been trying to come up with a workaround for a while and I haven't managed to find a solution as of yet. Is there a way I can determine the scroll height of the container as if the user had typed something on mount to expand the textarea to the same height?
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
    let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
     function auto_grow(element){
       element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) +"px"
    }
```

```css
    textarea{
       resize: none;
       overflow:  hidden;
       height: 1000px;
       font-size: 15px;
       line-height: 1.5em;
    
     }
```

```html
<textarea oninput = "auto_grow(textarea)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, this is where I currently am at the moment - I have amended the description and added photos to make it more clear

Comment: @user238433343, you don't include the code so I can't know what code you are using. Also, for the database, are you sure that you put it in the database becauseI don't think you could store `textarea` in database? Also, if it is a database, then you probably have to change the setting of your database or use other programming language because you can't simply just use javascript to create database.